# Populate a ComboBox with a Datatable within WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently creating an application which allows the user to insert various records within the selected SQL Database. What I would like to know is the most efficient way to populate the ComboBox with the required items extracted from an SQL table.

Below are current code snippets from my application.

Code snippet from my method Class:

```
public DataSet PullItems(string column, string db)
{
    using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(db))
    {
        using (DataSet dt = new DataSet())
        {
            //Check sql connection state
            if (!(SqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                //define stored commands and populate adapter
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("PullComboBoxItem", SqlCon))
                {
                    //define sql command types, timeout, and add procedure values
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.CommandTimeout = 3;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", column);

                    //fill data adapter and return
                    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

                    adap.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Error message to be impleme
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code Snippet from my WPF Window Class:

```
private void getItems(string id)
{
    if (CypherDef.CheckEnvironment(CypherDef.envir))
    {
         txt_deliverymethod.ItemsSource = CypherClass.PullItems(id, CypherDef.eprocurementDBConnection).Tables;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Lost to Database");
    }
}
```

XAML Code Snippet from the GUI:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="txt_deliverymethod" DisplayMemberPath="DeliveryMethod" Width="150" Margin="20,5,0,0" Height="25" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" SelectedIndex="0">
    <!--TODO:Delivery Method and auto fill combo box items on form load-->
</ComboBox>
```

Please forgive my sloppy code as I'm fairly new, however I do welcome tips and constructive criticism. Also if you believe my question is obscure I'd be pleased to elaborate.

Comment: what do you mean by : *know is the most efficient way to populate the combobox* ? Fetching the data from the Db usually the most time consuming part and setting items source sure not the performance bottleneck

Comment: You don't need to check the connection state because it is impossible for the connection to be open in the code you have shown. In fact, you don't even need to open it because the SqlDataAdapter will do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. 

@Vladmir: All I need is to populate the combo box with the current items within the SQL table column, this is called via an SQL stored procedure. This allows me to just add the relevant extra items within the database, negating the need to edit my project solution and manually add them in XAML. The problem which I have is I cannot bind these items from the DataSet to the ComboBox Collection programically on WPF load

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I'm used to checking the connection before most functions. It's more of an impulse in all honesty, I'll get this corrected. Many thanks for correcting my mistake

Comment: Thanks guys I've nows solved my problem. It was an error within my stored procedure. Kudos for you both for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was within my stored procedure. See below for the error and solution to my stored procedure.

Below is my mistake:

```
SELECT @column FROM [TABLE]
```

Below is my fix:

```
SET @STRSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' + @column + ' FROM [Table]'
EXECUTE SP_ExecuteSQL @STRSQL
```

Thank you again for your help.